# "help someone convince" vs "help someone to be convinced"?

Tags: passive-voice

---

His study of revolutionary writings and the injustices he saw **helped him convince that** Mexico should be free from colonial rule.

---

Do you think that sentence is correct?
If not, what do you think should be corrected?

Comment: Yeah that sounds wrong.  "helped him convince himself that", or "helped him be convinced that" would be expected.

Comment: Sorry, @Lynn, but your suggestions sound very awkward (especially the first one).

Comment: convinced him that... or if you insist on using help - helped convince him that...

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: @ErikKowal - I agree there are better ways to word it, I was trying to hold with the general structure of the original sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> His study of revolutionary writings and the injustices he saw helped to convince him that Mexico should be free from colonial rule.

Comment: Yes.  Also, the 'to' here is optional.